# Payara 5.193.1 - Cannot purge JBatch Repository

Tags: mysql, payara

I'm trying to purge JBatch repository with  *./asadmin purge-jbatch-repository server-config:jobs_/jobs* but I get the following error:

**remote failure: com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: You can't specify target table 'STEPEXECUTIONINSTANCEDATA' for update in FROM clause
java.sql.SQLException: You can't specify target table 'STEPEXECUTIONINSTANCEDATA' for update in FROM clause
Command purge-jbatch-repository failed.**

My datasource comes from a MySQL connection pool, connected to a server version 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1